# How to add values into key values in an array with corresponding names

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.

I'd like to integrate the values from `arr1` into the `thumbnail` key from `arr` with the corresponding names in Javascript. How do I do it?

If there is a duplicated question, Please let me know.

```
let arr = [{
   idx: 0,
   project_name: 'apple',
   thumbnail: null
}, {
   idx: 1,
   project_name: 'orange',
   thumbnail: null
}, {
   idx: 2,
   project_name: 'kiwi',
   thumbnail: null
}]

let arr1 = [
  'works/thumbnails/kiwi.png',
  'works/thumbnails/apple.png',
  'works/thumbnails/orange.png'
]
```

```
//output that I want is
[{
    idx: 0,
    name: 'apple',
    thumbnail: 'works/thumbnails/apple.png'
}, {
    idx: 1,
    name: 'orange',
    thumbnail: 'works/thumbnails/orange.png'
}, {
    idx: 2,
    name: 'kiwi',
    thumbnail: 'works/thumbnails/kiwi.png'
}]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Thank you all, I will make sure I will write what I have tried to solve a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go.

```js
let arr = [{
   idx: 0,
   project_name: 'apple',
   thumbnail: null
}, {
   idx: 1,
   project_name: 'orange',
   thumbnail: null
}, {
   idx: 2,
   project_name: 'kiwi',
   thumbnail: null
}]

let arr1 = [
  'works/thumbnails/kiwi.png',
  'works/thumbnails/apple.png',
  'works/thumbnails/orange.png'
]

arr.forEach(el => el.thumbnail = arr1.find(p => p.includes(el.project_name)))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Don't use `map` here. There is no reason to create a new array if `arr` also holds the result. This may let people think that the original `arr` is unchanged. Either change `map` into `forEach`  letting people know that `arr` changed. Or do use `map`, but create a shallow copy of the object.

Comment: @3limin4t0r here, i used forEach

Comment: @3limin4t0r hmm.. other solution could be assign `arr` to the mapped array.

Comment: Thank you all, you guys helped me a lot !!

Comment: With `forEach` you can omit the `return el` statement.

Comment: And the brackets too: `arr.forEach(el => 
   el.thumbnail = arr1.find(p => p.includes(el.project_name)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following code

```js
let arr = [
{idx: 0,project_name: 'apple',thumbnail: null}, 
{idx: 1,project_name: 'orange',thumbnail: null}, 
{idx: 2,project_name: 'kiwi',thumbnail: null}]

let arr1 = ['works/thumbnails/kiwi.png',  'works/thumbnails/apple.png',  'works/thumbnails/orange.png']


let newArray = arr.map((val, index) => ({ ...val, thumbnail: arr1.find(p => p.includes(val.project_name)) }));

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: You need to wrap your object in () when you do not have a return statement

Comment: NOTE: The image array is in different order!

Comment: Checking the element and then adding it to `newArray` seems to be working fine now.